# android add geofence within intentservice

Tags: java, android, service, geofencing

I want to add a geofence when the app recieves a gcm push, but I can not instantiate the GeofenceRequester because it needs to have an activity parameter. I have googled for a while and can't figure out how to instantiate it correctly.

When I run this code I get the following error:

> Error:(68, 52) error: incompatible types: GcmMessageHandler cannot be converted to Activity

My code in the IntentService looks so far:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    Double lat = Double.parseDouble(intent.getStringExtra("lat"));
    Double lng = Double.parseDouble(intent.getStringExtra("lng"));
    Float radius = Float.parseFloat("500");
    String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");

    addGeofence(lat, lng, radius);

    //showToast();

    Log.i("Data", "lat:" + lat + " lon:" + lng + " id:" + id);

    GcmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}


private void addGeofence(Double lat, Double lng, Float radius) {

    mGeofenceRequester = new GeofenceRequester(this);

    mRequestType = GeofenceUtils.REQUEST_TYPE.ADD;
    SimpleGeofence mGeofence = new SimpleGeofence(
            "1",
            lat,
            lng,
            radius,
            GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS,
            Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER);

    mCurrentGeofences.add(mGeofence.toGeofence());

    try {
        mGeofenceRequester.addGeofences(mCurrentGeofences);
    } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.add_geofences_already_requested_error,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

The GeofenceRequester class uses the activity parameter as following:

```
public class GeofenceRequester
                implements
                    OnAddGeofencesResultListener,
                    ConnectionCallbacks,
                    OnConnectionFailedListener {
   ...

   // Storage for a reference to the calling client
   private final Activity mActivity;

   ...

   public GeofenceRequester(Activity activityContext) {
      // Save the context
      mActivity = activityContext;

      ...
   }

   ...

   private GooglePlayServicesClient getLocationClient() {
      if (mLocationClient == null) {
          mLocationClient = new LocationClient(mActivity, this, this);
      }
      return mLocationClient;
   }

   ...

   // Later in another function
   msg = mActivity.getString(R.string.add_geofences_result_success,
         Arrays.toString(geofenceRequestIds));
}
```

Comment: Which line is the error on in your code? I'm guessing you need to pass it the activity in which it's running, so either use 'this' if you're in an activity class (although I suspect this isn't the case), or pass a reference to the activity when you instantiate the  GeofenceRequester. Your best bet is to look at the docs for GeofenceRequester and see what it needs the activity for, then you'll know what you need to pass in and why

Comment: The error is in the line right after defining the addGeofence function. mGeofenceRequester = new GeofenceRequester(this);

Comment: So you're trying to instantiate it in your GcmMessageHandler class, which doesn't inherit 'Activity', meaning it won't work. Read all of my previous comment, then give that a go

Comment: Okay, I try to understand what you mean. Meanwhile I have edited my post with the GeofenceRequester class to give you information, how the acitivity parameter is used.

Comment: I don't understand how to pass a reference..googled it but the only thing I get is headache..is there no easy way to do that? I found a similar post, but no answer to GeofenceRequester:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392732/create-android-geofence-in-background-without-crashing?rq=1

Comment: As in call addGeofence(Double lat, Double lng, Float radius, Activity callingActivity); - passing Activity in as a parameter

Comment: okay, so far so good...but I still don't have any activity to pass..it can't be null.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434999/android-geofence-only-works-with-opened-app?rq=1, as I think you're heading towards their solution

Comment: I guess I am dumb..I am new to Java, coming from Webdev..I really cannot figure out how to combine those two things..as I read, you don't have a clue either, but thanks anyway.